# Google Sheets: Prevent the NOW() function from updating when now is set based on another cell's input

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-sheets-formula

How can I prevent Google Sheets from updating NOW() on historical records? It seems to randomly update some of the dates and times when the sheet is opened or a new record is added.

The sheet is used by a small business to clock in and keep track of project hours, the records are added manually, throughout a workday.

Col A is added as the records date when the Tech selects their name from a dropdown list in Col B, formula: `=IFS(B43="","",A43="",NOW(),TRUE,A43)`, once they select the relevant task, and the project, they select START in Col F, which sets the starting time in Col H, formula: `=IF(H43,H43,IF(F43="START",NOW(),IF(F43="STOP","","")))`

Then once the task is complete, they select STOP in Col G, which sets the end time in I. formula: `=IF(I43,I43,IF(G43="STOP",NOW(),IF(G43="START","","")))`

I am not familiar with appscript and its functions, can someone please assist?

Tried various LAMBDA functions to no avail, and data validation also failed.

As indicated above, I am not familiar with appscript or coding, so I tried encasing my formula with the LAMBDA function, but it kept giving me an error as I needed to base the setting of the various dates and times on the other fields input.

Comment: NOW() is a volatile function which will recalculate whenever the sheet recalculates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Difficult to see exactly what you are doing as there is no example data to work from, however you can try passing `now` as a parameter to a `lambda` rather than calling it directly as this has the effect of making the `now` static (provided the outer `if` does not change). E.g. replace the first formula in your question with `=ifs(B43="","",A43="",lambda(x,x)(now()),true,A43)`

Comment: Thank you very much, added it in, seems to work will keep an eye on it. I Really appreciate the help!